# "C:\ProgramData\Package Cache" missing - how can I completely remove Visual Studio?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I am in the process of migrating some projects from an on-premise TFS server to Visual Studio Online.

Somehow, someone has removed the package cache folder (`C:\ProgramData\Package Cache`) from our build server and it is causing serious problems. I cannot install, modify or uninstall any components used by Visual Studio - not even Visual Studio itself.

Here's a screenshot of me trying to uninstall SSDT:

[image: Add / Remove programs window]

I tried removing Visual Studio from this panel as well, but all I got was a message stating that Visual Studio did not appear to be installed and that it would remove the item from the list. **But**, Visual Studio ***is*** installed on the machine - I can open it just fine!

So my question is, *how do I completely remove all traces of Visual Studio and it's components from my machine?*

Comment: What happens if you attempt to reinstall that same version?  obvious solution, install it on a virtual machine, locate this folder and transfer the data to the folder its indicating.

Comment: I cannot reinstall anything. From what I understand the installers/uninstallers for all these components are located in the folder that is missing. Even if this is possible I would need to find the specific versions of each of these components (which are not easy to find, believe me I've tried).

Comment: Every component is like this are just the specific one?  The simplest solution, run the same versions of VS you have installed, then choose to repair the installation.  At that point you should be able to remove VS properly.

Comment: I too have booted up my machine one day to find that my start menu and other programs are no longer working.  When I went to investigate why I found that Visual Studio 2015 ran, but like the OP my repair option failed with the above error and running the same setup showed that it thought it wasn't even installed (yet it runs fine!).  Office 2016 also failed to run and refused to repair or reinstall.  Eventually, I found that the package cache directory was just no longer there.